# Android , in app purchase , know if the user has already bought it

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have a button in my app for removing ads , and if the user buys it the ads are removed , I save it in sharedpreferences that the user has already bought it , but when you uninstall and install it again or clear data the sharedoreferences are deleted , so the ad shows again , how can I know that the user has already bought it ?

Comment: Can't you get that info in `QueryInventoryFinishedListener`?

Comment: what is that QueryInventory.... ?

Comment: That's part of the helper classes for in-app purchase. Doc [here](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html).

Comment: @user3693550 Are you consuming the purchase by calling `mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener)`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not have everything trigger server side? Once its been purchased save it on your server then get the unique id of the device and restore the ad blocker when the app first gets downloaded.

Comment: I don't have my own server, what server can I use and how?